# CSS - 100vh responsive image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple full screen layout that resizes an image so that it is only as big as the screen

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  background:teal;
  height:100vh;
}

.frame img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x2000/000000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am expceting the image to fit the screen, however using my example above it doesn't.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: should it be exactly as big as the screen or max. as big as the screen or exactly the same width as the screen?

Comment: I want it to be the height of the screen, so whatever device I am using to look at it I don't get scrollbars but see the whole image

Comment: You have only made the container element a specific height - but the auto height of the image in combination with its intrinsic _aspect ratio_ of course doesn’t stretch the image in a way that it would be distorted. And _“so that it is only as big as the screen”_ is a pretty unclear/vague requirement in that regard - do you want the image to be distorted if necessary, or do you want part either on top/bottom or left/right to be cut off?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  height:100vh;
}

.frame img {
  height: 100%;
  /* max-width: 100% --- if you want it to be max. 100% width of the screen but this will stretch the image */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x2000/000000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want a smoth background image for the whole site you can use this:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  height:100vh;
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/1500x2000/000000/fff");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: That works a lot better, thank you.  But by removing the max-width then the image is no longer responsive if the width of the page gets smaller

Comment: but if you use max-width the image will strech.... see my second solution  and check if this fits your needs

Answer (score 2):

You missed to set the size of the frame!
Use full height of the whole container with 100%.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  background:teal;
  height:100%;
}

.frame{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.frame img {
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x2000/000000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: finally found something that really does what it should!

Answer (score 0):

I just removed max-width to width at img css.

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
  background:teal;
  height:100vh;
}

.frame img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500x2000/000000/fff">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen responsive image background

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body { 
   background-image: url(http://ppcdn.500px.org/75319705/1991f76c0c6a91ae1d23eb94ac5c7a9f7e79c480/2048.jpg) ;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat:  no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size:  cover;
   background-color: #999;
  
}

div, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: exo, sans-serif;
  
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.message {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%; 
  height:45%;
  bottom: 0; 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="message">
    <h1>Responsive background</h1>
    <p>Fluid Layout</p>
  </div>
</div>
```